# Issue with NVIDIA A10 graphics card not recognized on Azure Windows 10 VM

Tags: c#, wpf, azure, nvidia, helix-3d-toolkit

I have created an Azure virtual machine `Standard NV12ads A10 v5` with `Windows 10 Pro` and installed the `NVIDIA A10` graphics card drivers. In the Windows 10 Task Manager, I can see the `NVIDIA A10` graphics card listed, indicating that it is functioning correctly.

However, when I run the dxdiag command, it shows the graphics card as `Microsoft Remote Display Adapter` instead of the `NVIDIA A10` graphics card.

Furthermore, I have developed a WPF application using `Visual Studio 2019` and `.NET Framework 4.7.2`. The purpose of this application is to display a 3D model from an .obj file using the `HelixToolKit.Wpf` v2.5.1 library. The application works fine on my local PC with an `NVIDIA GTX 970` graphics card. However, when I run the application on the Azure server, it experiences low FPS. The main components of the application are the XAML and C# files as follows:

**MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestHelixtoolkit.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:helix="http://helix-toolkit.org/wpf"
        Title="Model Viewer" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <helix:HelixViewport3D
            x:Name="Viewport3D"
            ZoomExtentsWhenLoaded="True"
            Background="Black"
            Orthographic="False"
            CameraRotationMode="Trackball"
            ShowViewCube="False"
            ShowCoordinateSystem="True"
            IsHeadLightEnabled="True"
            CalculateCursorPosition="True">
            <helix:SortingVisual3D Method="BoundingBoxCenter" CheckForOpaqueVisuals="True" SortingFrequency="1">
                <ModelVisual3D Content="{Binding ModelVisual3DContent}" />
            </helix:SortingVisual3D>
        </helix:HelixViewport3D>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Media3D;
using HelixToolkit.Wpf;

namespace TestHelixtoolkit
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Model3DGroup ModelVisual3DContent { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            var fileLoader = new ModelImporter();
            var model3D = fileLoader.Load("path\to\file.obj");
            ModelVisual3DContent = new Model3DGroup();
            ModelVisual3DContent.Children.Add(model3D);
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that the `Microsoft Remote Display Adapter` listed in dxdiag is causing the low FPS issue in my WPF application on the Azure server.

What could be the cause of this issue, and how can I ensure that the NVIDIA A10?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/enable-gpu-acceleration You have enabled Remote rendering? See the "Configure GPU-accelerated app rendering" section.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled both `Use hardware graphics adapters for all Remote Desktop Services sessions` and `Configure H.264/AVC hardware encoding for Remote Desktop connections` and `Prioritize H.264/AVC 444 Graphics mode for Remote Desktop connections` and then restarted the server